# GitHub pages deploy not updating on website

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I'm using Google Domains to host my site. I already have my site up and running, but I've added things in my repo and committed/pushed to the master branch.
I ran `npm run deploy`, then committed and pushed to master. I open my website and it's not showing my updates. This is a REACT page.
[image]

Does it matter if I'm running from master or gh-pages?

[image]

Comment: It certainly matters, but you'd need to tell us what's on each branch and where to tell you which you need to be using. What does `npm run deploy` *do*?

Comment: Master branch has the entire code from my react, and gh-pages has the css/images.js/static. I included a screenshot above.

Comment: So did you try serving from gh-pages? What happened?

Comment: Yes, I've switched the GitHub page source from master to gh-pages and keep trying back and forth, and it's still not showing my updates.

Comment: Please give a [mre]. As far as we can see serving from gh-pages should work, but you've given very little information to go on. If you can't share the repo, create a new one with the same basic setup minus any proprietary content (this is a useful debugging step anyway).

Comment: https://github.com/deannapi/portfolio-react

Comment: There's certainly *a* site at https://deannapi.github.io/portfolio-react, but the last commit on [the `gh-pages` branch](https://github.com/deannapi/portfolio-react/tree/gh-pages) is a week old so it's not surprising you're not seeing changes. You seem to have *two* deploy scripts, which is a bad idea.

Comment: Do I just commit directly to gh-pages then and not master?

Comment: You should be committing *source code changes* to `master`. The `deploy` script (you should only have *one*!) should use [`gh-pages`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages) to commit and push to `gh-pages`. Note you will need to `npm run build` to create the latest output (the easiest way is to add a script `"predeploy": "npm run build"` then it automatically happens when you `npm run deploy`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220224/discussion-between-deanna-martinez-and-jonrsharpe).